# Как лучше создать 3D график?

Tags: java, c++, python, api, 3d

Дана выборка точек с координатами X, Y и Z.

Задача 1. Необходимо отобразить эти точки каким-либо образом с помощью какого-либо API для графики.

Из языков программирования допустимо использовать Python, C++, Java (от более приоритетного к менее приоритетному соответственно).

Задача 2. Необходимо не просто отобразить точки, а нарисовать 3D график, желательно, плавно интерполирующий эти точки (би-кубической интерполяцией, например). При этом интерполирование происходит с помощью API.

Какой язык программирования и какой API вы бы использовали для решения данной задачи? Хотелось бы использовать что-то более высокоуровневое, чем OpenGL.

Comment: тут смотрите: https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html

Comment: @RafaelOsipov Спасибо:) Буду рад еще вариантам, просто чтобы потом выбрать из множества самый подходящий.

Comment: ищите в google `python 3d charting` и вариантов будет намного больше

Comment: [pyqtgraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/) посмотрите. Реализация более быстрая чем у `matplotlib`.

Comment: @Kromster JavaFX неплохая работа с 3D, но возможно питон будет лутше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот таким не особо сложным способом делается эта задача в Blender с плагином Animation Nodes. Внизу ноды, которые генерируют объект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интерполяция стандартным модификатором